# UITableView - what row was selected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a question - how can I get a number of row selected in a table? I am assigning it manually to a variable. The problem is that if a row was deselected, my variable still keeps the old value.

What can I do about it? Is there a method in UITableView that returns a number of a currently selected row?

Thank you in advance,
Ilya.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

If you haven't implemented a delegate (see nduplessis), UITableView also offers:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow
```

Comment: Thank you, Jarret, that is what I needed. Now everything is working perfectly.

Comment: And for anyone looking for the multiple selection version, it's `- (NSArray *)indexPathsForSelectedRows`

Comment: The issue with this method is that whenever it is called, even when the user has not selected anything, it gives back 0.

Comment: If the user hasn't selected anything, it actually returns nil (Apple's docs: `An index path identifying the row and section indexes of the selected row or nil if the index path is invalid.`). Remember that sending a message to nil is allowed, and in this case [myNilIndexPath row] is returning 0 because myNilIndexPath is nil. Checking that the object returned from indexPathForSelectRow isn't nil should solve the issue.

Comment: @JarretHardie thank you. Wouldn't it make MORE sense if it had NSNotFound as a value for section?

Comment: @Alehar That would be wonderful, but it would require that myNilIndexPath was actually an instance of NSIndexPath. In this case it's nothing... just nil, so there's no ability for any index-path-aware code to interpret the call and return a more nuanced value. The declared return value type is NSUInteger, so that's why you get a default 0.

Comment: Well, what about if there are several indexPathForSelectedRow

Comment: `- (NSArray *)indexPathsForSelectedRows` gives you any multiple selections.

Answer (score 36):

The UITableViewDelegate will call

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

when a row is selected. From this you can easily determine the row by using indexPath.section and indexPath.row